# Weblogic hostname verification anomalies

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm developing a webapp with a webservice for a WL 12.1.2 server. The information it sends/recieves does not contain any secret information, so my advisers told me to disable SSL hostname verification.
After some research, I found that turning the option off in the Admin Consol doesn't help.
Then I found that, I have to write '-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true' in server start. After this, when I restart the server it still doesn't work, but when I log in to the Admin Console, it passes validation. But after a while it resets, and goes back to not skipping validation, thus failing the program.

Do you have any idea how to keep this option turned off, how to make it stable, or any other way to make it work?

I tried adding the certificate information to the Demo Trusts, Certs, but the weblogic hostname verifier somehow doesn't understand that 123.asd.com should be accepted by a *.asd.com cert. If there is a way, I'd like to skip the whole thing instead of overwriting the ssl verifier.

Thanks in advance!
Botond

Comment: In the admin console did you turn it off for every server on the SSL tab (change it to None)? Have you tried adding `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true` to the weblogic start script startWebLogic.sh or setDomainEnv.sh ? It sounds like something is wrong with your config, not a problem with Weblogic itself

Comment: On this WL server I only have 1 server, and yes, I changed it to None. By the way, I usually start the server from Eclipse, could that cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I have found the solution of the problem I was encountering.
The problem was that I thought that changing stuff in the admin console would be saved and loaded every time I started the server, but the truth is, it is not.
I had to add the following line to the startWebLogic.cmd script: "set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true" and this worked. Now the server starts as it should, and it always skips the verification as I wanted. There are no anomalies!

Answer (score 0):

This screenshot speaks all:

***-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true***

[image]